# $pristine not working properly?

Tags: forms, angularjs

I made a button to clear all the data in form. It is working fine for the first time, but when you fill form for second time and then try to clear it , it doesnt. where am I wrong.

```
var defaultform = {
department: "",
program: "",
}

$scope.clear = function (formdata) {

$scope.myform.$setPristine;
$scope.formdata = defaultform;

};


<div class="divbutton2">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-   click="clear(formdata);">
Clear
</button>
</div>
```

here's my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/rHGyBkQNocmtKcXPCjI3?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first time you press the button and do `$scope.formdata = defaultform;`, the `defaultform` becomes the `formdata` and gets the input. The button still works, replacing `defaultform` with itself, therefore **seems** not to be working.

Just do `$scope.formdata = anglar.copy(defaultform);` and do not touch the `defaultform` in any other way.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nikos. That was helpful. Also, you made concept clear.